# Как реализовать создание чата в Telegram Bot имея номер телефона?

Tags: java, telegram-bot

Для курсового проекта пытаюсь реализовать бота в Telegram.
Подскажите, куда глянуть или как быть?
Имеется база пользователей с номерами телефонов, можно ли, имея номер телефона, получить TelegramUserId и создать чат с ним?

Comment: Ботам запрещено первыми заводить разговор, иначе было бы куча спама.

Comment: Ну на сколько я знаю , во избежания спама - бот не может отправлять сообщения пользователю , пока тот не даст согласие,нажав кнопку старт ,можно ли как то хотя бы инициализировать чат ?

Comment: Как и сказали выше - бот не имеет возможности первым начинать разговор, но вы можете реализовать клиент телеграма, который будет имитировать действия от лица настоящего аккаунта(там будет доступна желанная ф-ция). Быть может есть какие либы для реализации данного действия на яве, знаю что для питона используется Telethon, должны быть аналоги и на другие языки)